# Equality of almost equal lists

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

Can you help me with this common problem I have?

Given two lists:

```
a={339.66666666666697`, -287.4444444444446`, 0.`}
```

and

```
b = {339.6666666666667`, -287.44444444444684`, -2.1316282072803006`*^-13}
```

`Equal[a,b]` gives `False` because

```
-2.1316282072803006`*^-13
```

is not equal to `0`.

How can I solve this problem? I understand that it is something about precision settings, but I don't know how to write this.

Comment: Another helpful function could be `PossibleZeroQ`

Comment: I would do `a - b // Norm // Chop` but for very large lists the sum of the errors accumulate so then you might want to only check the maximal error in the list with `a - b // Norm[#, Infinity] & // Chop`. That said they output 0 rather than `True`.

Answer (score 6):

```
a = {339.66666666666697, -287.4444444444446, 0.}
b = {339.6666666666667, -287.44444444444684, -2.1316282072803006*^-13}
```

---

In order to chop values close to zero to exactly zero and compare:

```
Chop[a] == Chop[b]
```

> True

Chop takes a second argument as well.

---

For checking up to 3 decimal places:

```
Round[a, 10^-3] == Round[b, 10^-3]
```

> True

---

To within a multiple of the second argument:

```
Round[a, 10^-#] == Round[b, 10^-#] & /@ Range[15]
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, 
> False, False, False, False}

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this:

```
Equal[a, Chop[b]] (*True*)
```

---

```
SetAccuracy[a, 10] === SetAccuracy[b, 10] (*True*)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may define a function, that compares two numbers or arrays, where you can specify how much difference you want to tolerate: E.g.

```
equalBy[a_, b_, tol_] := Max[Abs[a - b]] <= tol;
```

where a and b are the objects to compare and tol is the allowed tolerance.

Now with your example:

```
a = {339.66666666666697`, -287.4444444444446`, 0.`};
b = {339.6666666666667`, -287.44444444444684`,-2.1316282072803006`*^-13};
```

the largest difference is:

```
Max[Abs[a - b]]  (*2.21689*10^-12*)
```

and we may write:

```
equalBy[a, b, 10^-12]  (* False *)

equalBy[a, b, 10^-11]  (True *)
```